# jQuery animation not working as intended

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an addition to a form appear when clicking on a button. I have 2 problems with this: Why is not the new buttons completely hidden in the beginning? I tried to give them height of 0 and padding and such... And why does the reveal new buttons animation take longer time than the rest of the animation?

A demo http://jsfiddle.net/mNRem/

This is my jQuery code:

```
var duration = 3000;
var showWidth = "150px";
var formHidden = true;
var showHeight = $("#cancel-button").outerHeight(true)+"px";
var buttonPadding = $('#cancel-button').css("padding");
var buttonBorder = $('#cancel-button').css("border-width");
$('#new-name').width(0);
$('.hidden-form').height(0);
$('.buttons').css({padding: 0, "border-width": 0});
$('#change-form-button').click(function() {
  formHidden = !formHidden;
  var labelWidth  = formHidden? "0" : showWidth;
  var buttonWidth = formHidden? showWidth : "0";
  $('#new-name').animate({width: labelWidth}, duration);
  $('#change-form-button').animate({width: buttonWidth, padding: "0", "border-width": "0"}, duration);
  $('.hidden-form').animate({height: showHeight}, duration);
  $('.buttons').animate({padding: buttonPadding, "border-width": buttonBorder}, duration);
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hide buttons use css prop: `display: none;`

Or better for you jQuery statement $('.buttons').css({ display: 'none' });

For better animation try to use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) functions:

```
$('.buttons').hide("fast");
```

And then on click

```
$('.buttons').show();
```

Look here: [Example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mNRem/2/)

Comment: If anybody should be interested, here is the much simpler code: http://jsfiddle.net/mNRem/3/